# Java set array size of 2D-array after declaration

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that should return a 2D-array which is always structured like this:

`int [][] = {{100}, {5}, {1,5,7,8,30,60,...}`

My problem is that when I call the method I don't know how long the 3rd array will be. This is my code right now:

```
public static int[][] readFile(int max, int types, String fileName) {

    int [][]result = new int[3][];
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;
        int currentLine = 0;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(line);
            if (currentLine == 0) {
                result[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
                result[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);

            }else if (currentLine == 1) {
                int []theSlices = new int[numbers.length];
                result[2][0] = theSlices; //-> obviously error
                for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
                    theSlices[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
                }

                return result;
            }
            currentLine++;


        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ;
    return null;
}
```

My code right now is obviously not working but how can I fix it? Happy for every help :)

Comment: `result[2] = theSlices;`

Comment: *FYI:* Use try-with-resource, because your current code will leave the file open, and that's a memory leak.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: You search the web for [`try-with-resource`](https://www.google.com/search?q=try-with-resource) to learn more about it.

Comment: fair enough, thanks :D